# CRC Calculation Of Byte Array in C#

Tags: c#, byte, modbus, crc

I am trying to port a piece of code that has been written in C language into C#. The purpose of the code is to calculate the CRC of an array of bytes. But so far I failed. My byte array looks something like this:

```
data = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

And the C code I am trying to port to C# is as follows.

```
unsigned  int  crc_val(unsigned char* data_val, unsigned char data_len) 
{   
    int i;
    unsigned int crc_value=0ffff;
    while(data_len--)
    {
        crc_value^=*data_ val++;
        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            if(crc_value&0x0001)
                crc_value=(crc_value>> 1)^0xa001;
            else
                crc_value=crc_value>> 1;
        }
    }
    return (crc_value);
 }
```

Right now I have this:

```
private void GetCRC(byte[] message, ref byte[] CRC)
{
    ushort CRCFull = 0xFFFF;
    char CRCLSB;

    for (int i = 0; i < (message.Length) - 2; i++)
    {
        CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ message[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            CRCLSB = (char)(CRCFull & 0x0001);
            CRCFull = (ushort)((CRCFull >> 1) & 0xFFFF);
            if (CRCLSB == 1)
                CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ 0xA001);
        }
    }
    CRC[1] = (byte)((CRCFull >> 8) & 0xFF);
    CRC[0] = (byte)(CRCFull & 0xFF);
}
```

Please, please, please... Teach me how this code is written in C#, I am a quick learner and once I see the C# implementation of the above function, I shall pick it up from there and finish my application. I thank you for your attention and wish you all spend a fabulous day.

Comment: If you show us the C# code you have, we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: I edited my question and added what I have so far. Thank you for your interest in looking into my question, Sir.

Comment: The C code has an error. The `0ffff` needs to be `0xffff`. Did you copy and paste the code, or did you attempt to type it in?

Comment: Why `(message.Length) - 2`?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Do you have a test sequence of bytes and the desired CRC for that sequence?

Comment: I fixed the 0xffff issue in my code. I was actually trying modified versions of various CRC codes across the web. I am so new to this concept and I believe I can learn how to convert this CRC code to C# in this website. I know it is not working because my transponder flashes green when I send data but its yellow lamp is not flashing, and I am not seeing any incoming bytes on my COM monitor. The connection also gives a timeout error at times.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- unsigned char* -> `byte[]` or `Span<byte>` or `IEnumerable<byte>`
- There is no need for a separate data_len parameter, just about all c# collections know their length, the only real exception would be raw pointers, but there is little need for those since the introduction of `Span<T>`
- 0ffff -> looks like a typo, I assume 0xffff is intended
- change your loop to a foreach, or for-loop i.e.

  ```
  foreach(var b in data_val){ 
      crc_value^=b; 
      ...
  }
  ```
- bit operations should work the same way
- You need to figure out what the length of the datatype is, `unsigned int` is *minimum* 16 bits, but may be 32 bit. In c# an uint is 32 bits, and ushort is 16 bit.
- If you need to convert numbers to byte[] or vice versa, see [BitConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-6.0)
- C# has no implicit number to bool conversion, you need to do it explicitly, i.e. `number != 0`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am converting the code per your instructions and so far I got this:

Comment: int crc_val()
        {
            int i; int j = 0; int data_len=data.Length;
            int crc_value = 0xffff;
            while ((data_len--)>0)
            {
                crc_value ^= data[j++];
                for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    if (crc_value & 0x0001)
                        crc_value = (crc_value >> 1) ^ 0xa001;
                    else
                        crc_value = crc_value >> 1;
                }
            }
            return (crc_value);
        }

Comment: But the    "if (crc_value & 0x0001)" says "int cannot be converted to bool". What can I do about it?

Comment: @Ahmet You need to do `(crc_value & 0x0001) != 0` to convert to bool, there is no implicit conversion from number to bool in c#

Comment: Thank you very much! At least now my code doesn't generate a compile error. However now the machine is not responding to my Modbus command. I guess it will be too specific to ask for help from over here. I will contact the manufacturer. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Ahmet whenever porting code, it is very useful to have unit tests that ensures that the original and ported version give the same result for the same input. That should give you some confidence that the code works as intended.